# Convert call back to promise

Tags: javascript, loopback

I am trying to convert one loopback callback function to promise, but I am not able to convert it. The code for is

```
let ds = app.datasources.ace_db
ds.connector.execute(sql,[],(err, data ) => {
   console.log('datalogger', data);
});
```

Is there any method to convert this peace of code to promise?

Comment: Show what you tried that isn't working

Comment: possible duplicate. check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432401/replacing-callbacks-with-promises-in-node-js

Comment: Related [github issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/418#issue-38984704) about Promise support in LoopBack.

Comment: you can also use async npm package [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a [`Promise.promisify()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html)

```
let p = Promise.promisify(ds.connector.execute);
p(sql, []).then(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is wrap your `ds.connector.execute` in a `Promise`, and return that `Promise` like so:

```
const dsConnectorPromise = function(sql, arr) {

    let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        ds.connector.execute(sql, arr, (err, data) => {

            if(err) reject(err);
            else resolve(data);
        });
    });

    return p; // return promise
};
```

You can then go on to use `dsConnectorPromise` like so:

```
dsConnectorPromise(sql, []).then(data => {

    console.log(data);

}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: or you can just do `return new Promise((resolve, reject)...` without assigning to a `p` variable at all